# To Delete or Not to Delete Arcserve Makeup Jobs?

Tags: backup

Every once in a while, I have a backup job that fails with my backup server running ARCserve 12.5. A failure results in the creation of a 'makeup' job. I run the makeup job and even if it completes it stays in my job cue. These have piled up over the past couple of years and I find myself wondering if its ok to delete them knowing that ARCserve relies on a sql database to catalog backup info and data.

If I run a makeup job, can I just delete it afterward? Should I just collect them? I have not seen anything so far that makes me feel confident with what to do with these leftover jobs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to delete the old makeup jobs with no ill effects AFAIK -- worse case as long as you still have the tape you can scan it and recover the job information at restore time (so don't delete any make-up jobs you may need to restore soon).

Note that you can also disable the creation of make-up jobs (if you're getting notified of job failures you can just re-run the regular job later rather than doing a make-up job) -- that avoids the backlog of make-up jobs sitting around.

Comment: Thanks guys! This one had left me scratching my head and this at least gives me the basis to decide how to handle these extra jobs from now on.

Answer (score 3):

It's perfectly safe to delete them. The backup jobs are not required for a restore, so unless you wanted to rerun them for any reason there's no point in hanging on to them. As voretaq7 said, you can always restore the job catalogue from the tapes themselves, even if the job itself has been deleted from the database.

Answer (score 1):

This may or may not help:

I have had a different experience with deleting the makeup jobs. I had about 6 makeup jobs to delete. I removed the extras and in the process somehow deleted the original but left behind a makeup job. I renamed my makeup job to take the (makeup #6) part out of the job name. This was a bad idea.

My backup still goes through. My data still writes to the drive and onto my tape and can be read back off of it later. However my entire "Job History" tab has stopped working. If it wasn't for the Job Log tab visible at "Job Status" then I would have no record of my job. It is taking this job log and appending each time.  I'm a few months in and it's getting long and when there is an issue it's hard to find it in this long long file.

So, learn from me and don't accidentally delete your original and think that renaming the makeup job will just work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can Modify the makeup job, save it to a file, create a new job, load the file and voilà! Submit it again as a brand new job. Might do it ;)